# Проблема с отправкой файла на сервер | PHP 8.x, Laravel 9.x

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Пытаюсь отправить файл через ajax, этим инструментом работаю давно, но никогда не получалось отправлять файлы, не знаю в чем ошибка, все гайды по проблеме прочитаны, но у всех одно решение.

```
   img.onclick = function(){
   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', file[i]);
   console.log(formData.get('file'));
   $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
   });
   $.ajax({
          url: '{{route('get_image')}}',
          type:'post',
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          async: false,
          data: {file: formData},
          success: function(response){
                      console.log(response);
                   }
     })
}
```

Как видно, пытаюсь привязать событие к картинке, по клику срабатывает отправка на сервер, где можно поработать с файлом, в консольке файл красиво выводится, он существует, но на сервер не приходит и я не понимаю почему, может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Как сам файл смотрите? добавьте `return response()->json(request()-> allFiles());` и покажите что возвращается

Comment: "но на сервер не приходит"
Может быть сервер проверить? Лог какой-нибудь, что файл пришел

Comment: на сервере делаю dd($request->all()) или ($request->files())
возвращается пустота

Comment: как только убираю из опций ajax
```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```
и в данные засовываю текстовые значения, ответ появляется
если эти же тестовые отправить при тех опциях - ничего не будет

Comment: @YuriuSemetsky $request - откуда переменная, покажите. Ещё файл посмотрите в $_FILES - присутствует?

Comment: Выложите еще html код формы. Пожалуйста.